# How to load controller of a module in the class?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have tried many different ways to solve this that I have found online but they have not worked, so please can someone help me.

I am getting this error

Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Form_Login' not found in pathToProject/modules/admin/controllers/LoginController.php on line 13

my project is

Application

--- modules

------admin

--------controllers

--------forms

--------models

--------views

------default

--------controllers

--------forms

--------models

--------views

------aboutus

--------controllers

--------forms

--------models

--------views
etc
etc

My Controller

```
class Admin_LoginController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

  public function init()
  {
     /* Initialize action controller here */
  }

  public function indexAction()
  {
      $form = new Admin_Form_Login();
      $this->view->form = $form;
      // action body
  }
}
```

My Form

```
class Admin_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{

public function init()
{
    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */

    $this->setAction("/admin/index/login")->setMethod("post");

    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
    $username->setLabel('Username')
    ->setOptions(array('size' => '30'));


    $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
    $password->setLabel('Password')
    ->setOptions(array('size' => '30'));


    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setLabel('Log in')
    ->setOptions(array('class' => 'submit'));

    $this->addElement($username)
    ->addElement($password)
    ->addElement($submit);


}


}
```

MY Bootstrap.php

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload() {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Admin_',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH."/modules/admin",
    ));
    return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

Here is my App ini maybe something in there

```
[bootstrap]

Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Admin_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Default_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Aboutus_"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.modules[] = ""

resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

admin.resources.layout.layout = layout
admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
default.resources.layout.layout = default
default.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

and my view

```
$this->form
```

Thanks for any help.

---

I added the following in the production part ok my application.ini and it started worked Not sure why.

```
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Admin_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Default_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Aboutme_"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.modules[] = ""

resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
```

Comment: Your `Admin_Bootstrap`, presumably stored in `application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php`, extends `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`, which registers its own resource autoloader. You could probably remove your custom `Admin_Bootstrap::_initAutoload()` method.

Comment: Is your form class at `application/modules/admin/forms/Login.php`?

Comment: yes it is at application/modules/admin/forms/Login.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}
```

**There's no namespace (only if you had one i.e. Application_).**

As for the config file:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =

resources.layout.layout = "layout"
default.resources.layout.layoutPath = "/views/layout"
admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = "/views/layout" 

[staging : production]


[testing : production]

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Comment: The down voter probably doesn't understand about ZF namespaces. Either way, if this is not enough it's still the right way. It's not module namespace "admin", but application namespace, if you had one (i.e. Application_).

Comment: Try the the config I've just posted @David

Comment: @David Glad it worked. It would be nice to remove this down vote by up voting =P

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Dave, empty your Admin_Bootstrap class. If you need any _init methods put them in your application level bootstrap. All bootstrap classes run on every request anyway, so put any _init methods at the application level to prevent inadvertent overrides.

Ensure you module bootstrap is at `application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php` (*every module needs a bootstrap*) this ensure that the resource autoloaders work correctly. Forms are a [predefined resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module) in the autoloader so no _init method is needed.

Ensure your application.ini includes the minimum required to activate modules:

```
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

and lastly don't forget to `echo` in your views:

```
$this->form
```

should be:

```
echo $this->form
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

in application/configs/application.ini

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

in application/Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    /**
     * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
     */
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
        return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

in modules/admin/Bootstrap.php

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

The login form must reside in *modules/admin/forms* and the controller in *modules/admin/controllers*.

I hope to check out was helpful!

Comment: My bootstrip is in

application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php

And I have tried it with and without the

_initAutoload()

method

My form is in

modules/admin/forms

Mu application.ini has

resources.modules[] = ""

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"